# Transcode to virtual device/memory in VLC

Tags: c#, html, ffmpeg, video-streaming, transcoding

I have a unicast h264 stream from a video transmitter. Now, I would like to view the stream in a web browser using HTML5s  tag. For this, I have to transcode it first via VLC to theora/ogg and then streaming it out as a HTTP stream. This works fine for 1 client, but since HTTP streaming isn't multicast, I have the fear that my server will break down really quick because VLC will transcode the input stream for every additional client request.

For this reason, I'd like to write the transcoded stream in something like a 'virtual device' or memory or any other form of temporary storage (but dear god, NO files, I don't want to destroy my hard disk). Then, I would like to grab the transcoded stream with a secondary VLC instance and stream it via HTTP, so that in the end, I have to transcode it only once for all clients.

In steps:

1. [DONE] Grab H.264 unicast stream from transmitter via RTSP
2. VLC instance 1 transcodes it to theora/ogg and writes it to a temporary memory
3. VLC instance 2 reads from the memory and streams it via HTTP
4. [DONE] Browser requests HTTP stream via HTTP live Streaming (html5 video).

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 0):

using Windows Media Server, this could be done. Please check out this details.

http://blogs.iis.net/chriskno/archive/2008/07/14/sourcing-from-a-multicast-broadcast-using-windows-media-services.aspx